# How to publish messages to mqtt from views [django]?

Tags: django, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to integrate paho.mqtt into django to publish msgs to mosquitto broker, I have searched but I havent found much tutorials on how I can achieve it.

Well i tried to put this code into mqtt.py:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

topic = "#topic#"

def connect_mqtt()  -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)
    client = mqtt_client.Client(topic)
    client.username_pw_set('#username#', '#psswd#')
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect('####the host##', 1883)
    return client


def publish(client):
    msg = 'test test'
    result = client.publish(topic, msg)



def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    publish(client)
    client.loop_forever()
```

and in **init**.py

```
from . import mqtt

client.loop_start()
```

and when I call run() on views it doesn't work, and runserver it doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Can somebody explain to me how should I structure my files and system to do it right.

Please any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to just publish a single message from a view? Could you use the `single()` function? https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#single

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: can you please explain to me when we use the class as the code shown above? do we use it when we need continuous connection between clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone wants to publish a message from a views function. Use paho-mqtt

```
# inside views.py
# you can modify whether to publish from get/post method.
from django.http import HttpResponse
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
def publish(request):
    
    publish.single("your pub topic", payload="Your message", hostname="broker url", port=1883)

    return HttpResponse("Published")
```

.

```
# inside urls.py
from . import views
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path("publish", views.publish, name="mqtt_publish"),
]
```

This one will publish to the topic when you go to `host/publish`